# Android Horizontal Text View off screen

Tags: android, screen, swipe, horizontal-scrolling

So I'm making an app and I want to have a horizontal scroll bar filled with letters, each letter represents a note.

I want to be able to swipe sideways to select the different notes, with 1 note centred at all times.
It would work the way the G String's android app does. How do they go about getting this effect? Since there are quite a few notes, the ones that do not fit on the screen would be off screen and come onto the screen when swipped in.

Picture for reference: http://tinyurl.com/cf2v9ke

Any help at all even just pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a "snapping" effect, where the currently selected note is centered, I think you can use a `ViewPager`. Check out [Mark Murphy's blog post about this](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html), it looks like a good example.

Comment: That's great man thanks for that should help a bunch!
How would I go about making the horizontal scroll start on a middle element in the horizontal scroll view? Say my scroll starts at A, but I want it to start in the middle at E, so the user can swipe left or right from the start? How would I go about doing that? Thanks :)

Comment: `ViewPager` has a method called [setCurrentItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) which you can call to have it start in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a HorizontalScrollView in which you add layouts. All standard behavior for the rest.